# Validate php form

Tags: php, forms, validation

```
<?php
include('backoffice/dbconnect.php');
if(isset($_POST['contact_submitted']))
{
    $nome      = $_POST["name"];
    $email   = $_POST["email"];
    $mensagem  = $_POST["message"];
    if (empty($nome)) {
        $noname = '<span  class="error">Insira o seu nome!</span></br>';
        echo $noname;
    }
    if (empty($email)) {
        $noemail = '<span  class="error">Insira o seu email!</span></br>';
        echo $noemail;
    }
    if (empty($mensagem)) {
        $nomensagem = '<span  class="error">Insira uma mensagem!</span></br>';
        echo $nomensagem;
    }
    else
    {
        global $email;
        mail ("pedrofidalgo@live.com.pt","$nome, Contato Turismo Murtoseiro",
              "Nome: $nome\n Email: $email\n Mensagem: $mensagem\n");

        $sucesso = '<span  class="yes">Mensagem enviada com sucesso!</span>';
        echo $sucesso;
    }
} //END IF
?>
```

Whats wrong with this code? I want to validate all fields, and if none of them are empty, send the message. If all are empty its ok, but if i $mensagem got something, it says "echo $sucesso;" but all others fields are empty, so its not suppost to happen ..

Comment: Please, clarify your question. We are not in your head.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users

Comment: @Ankit When you visit someone's home, you usually learn how to behave and then do something. SO has really too much questions "This doesn't work, why?". Since we gave our time for free in answering, OP should at least don't be lazy and detail what they need instead of copy/paste the code and then say... "They will solve the problem for me"

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa i don't want to do unnecessary debate but 'We are not in your head' doesn't sounds good to me.

Comment: [Don't forget to **take the SO Tour** it will guide you on how to best use SO](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: @Ankit "Solve my problems for me and even understand what my problems actually are because I don't know/want to explain more detail", doesn't sound good too.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (empty($nome)) {
    $noname = '<span  class="error">Insira o seu nome!</span></br>';
    echo $noname;
}
else if (empty($email)) {
    $noemail = '<span  class="error">Insira o seu email!</span></br>';
    echo $noemail;
}
else if (empty($mensagem)) {
    $nomensagem = '<span  class="error">Insira uma mensagem!</span></br>';
    echo $nomensagem;
}
else
{
    global $email;
    mail ("pedrofidalgo@live.com.pt","$nome, Contato Turismo Murtoseiro",
                    "Nome: $nome\n Email: $email\n Mensagem: $mensagem\n"
    );
    $sucesso = '<span  class="yes">Mensagem enviada com sucesso!</span>';
    echo $sucesso;
}
```

It happens only for condition `if` and `else`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty($nome)) {
    $noname = '<span  class="error">Insira o seu nome!</span></br>';
    echo $noname;
}
if (empty($email)) {
    $noemail = '<span  class="error">Insira o seu email!</span></br>';
    echo $noemail;
}
if (empty($mensagem)) {
    $nomensagem = '<span  class="error">Insira uma mensagem!</span></br>';
    echo $nomensagem;
} 
if(!empty($nome) && !empty($email) && !empty($mensagem))
{
    global $email;
    mail ("pedrofidalgo@live.com.pt","$nome, Contato Turismo Murtoseiro",
                    "Nome: $nome\n Email: $email\n Mensagem: $mensagem\n"
    );
    $sucesso = '<span  class="yes">Mensagem enviada com sucesso!</span>';
    echo $sucesso;
}
```

This will also show multiple validation errors in case multiple fields are empty.
That's why i have used simple `if` statements instead of `if else if..else` statement

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are missing `else` statements between your ifs...

```
<?php
    include('backoffice/dbconnect.php');
    if(isset($_POST['contact_submitted']))
        {
            $nome      = $_POST["name"];
            $email   = $_POST["email"];
            $mensagem  = $_POST["message"];
            if (empty($nome)) {
                $noname = '<span  class="error">Insira o seu nome!</span></br>';
                echo $noname;
            } else if (empty($email)) {
                $noemail = '<span  class="error">Insira o seu email!</span></br>';
                echo $noemail;
            } else if (empty($mensagem)) {
                $nomensagem = '<span  class="error">Insira uma mensagem!</span></br>';
                echo $nomensagem;
            } else {
                global $email;
                mail ("pedrofidalgo@live.com.pt","$nome, Contato Turismo Murtoseiro",
                "Nome: $nome\n Email: $email\n Mensagem: $mensagem\n"
            );
            $sucesso = '<span  class="yes">Mensagem enviada com sucesso!</span>';
            echo $sucesso;
        }
    } //END IF
?>
```

But this only display one error message at once.
You can set one error variable and store error strings in it and then check if this string is empty, if yes send email etc, if not echo string

```
<?php
    include('backoffice/dbconnect.php');
    if(isset($_POST['contact_submitted']))
        {
            $nome      = $_POST["name"];
            $email     = $_POST["email"];
            $mensagem  = $_POST["message"];
            // initialize error variable
            $error     = '';
            if (empty($nome)) {
                $error .= '<span  class="error">Insira o seu nome!</span></br>';
            } if (empty($email)) {
                $error .= '<span  class="error">Insira o seu email!</span></br>';
            } if (empty($mensagem)) {
                $error .= '<span  class="error">Insira uma mensagem!</span></br>';
            }
            if ($error == '') {
                global $email;
                mail ("pedrofidalgo@live.com.pt","$nome, Contato Turismo Murtoseiro",
                "Nome: $nome\n Email: $email\n Mensagem: $mensagem\n"

                $sucesso = '<span  class="yes">Mensagem enviada com sucesso!</span>';
                echo $sucesso;
            } else {
                echo $error;
            };
        }
    } //END IF
?>
```